# How to put the output of a function into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def sentiment_analyzer_scores(sentence):
    for sentence in df['clean_text']:
        score =analyser.polarity_scores(sentence)

        print({<40{}".format(sentence,str(score)))

print(sentiment_analyzer_scores(df['clean_text'])
```

This is the code I want to put the output into a dataframe what do I do?

Comment: use `return` - but you woulnd need first put all values in list and then return list. OR concatenate all strings in one string.

Comment: do you want to put in the same DataFrame in new column? Maybe you should use `.apply()`

Answer (score 1):

In general you can create a new column in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['hello', 'bye']})
df['len'] = df['col'].apply(len)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     col  len
0  hello    5
1    bye    3
```

In your case I think that something like this should work:

```
df['new_column'] = df['clean_text'].apply(analyser.polarity_scores)
```

where `polarity_scores`is the function that you want to apply

Or something like this:

```
df['new_column'] = df['clean_text'].apply(lambda x:"{}<40{}".format(x, str(analyser.polarity_scores(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data from function you would have to keep all strings on list - without `print()` and use `return` to return it

```
def sentiment_analyzer_scores(data):
    results = []
    for sentence in data:
        score = analyser.polarity_scores(sentence)
        text = "{<40{}".format(sentence, str(score))
        results.append(text)

    return results

df['results'] = sentiment_analyzer_scores(df['clean_text'])
```

or in new `DataFrame`

```
results = sentiment_analyzer_scores(df['clean_text'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

But maybe you should use `.apply()` instread of `for`-loop

More or less

```
def sentiment_analyzer_scores(sentence):
    score = analyser.polarity_scores(sentence)
    returm "{<40{}".format(sentence, str(score))

df['results'] = df['clean_text'].apply(sentiment_analyzer_scores)
```

or in new `DataFrame`

```
results = df['clean_text'].apply(sentiment_analyzer_scores)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```